# Post call with Rest API whose @RequestBody is Entity

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an entity class like the one below:

```
@Entity
public class Marks {
    @Id 
    private String id;
    int marks;
}
```

I am trying to call the below POST call:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/marks",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> saveMarks(@RequestBody Marks marks) {
        log.info("Inside saveMarks"); 
}
```

When I call this api, I am getting:

> 400: Bad Request
>
> The request api : http://localhost:8888/marks Content-Type:
>   application/json Request payoad : {"id": "12345","marks":80}

Comment: Post the details for your `POST` request, especially the request body

Comment: @AliDehghani: Posted the request details.

Comment: First off you should send a request to `/marks` endpoint not  `/referralCode `

Comment: Sorry. I tried with /marks and getting the same issue.

Comment: Do you have anything configured that will convert `80` to `Marks` instance?

Comment: No, Marks is an entity.

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for private field?

Comment: @user2086580 what do you mean? I don't remember anything in Spring that converts `@Entity` class without any additional configuration

Comment: can you post the code for the whole entity?

Comment: Yes, I have getters and setters and @Entity (com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity)  comes under Objectify.

Comment: I am able to solve the problem.I just created the new Entity class with existing fields and it started working.However I didn't find any difference between the old and new Entity.Thank you for all your help.